# Referencing multiple Checkboxes in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-preferences, android-checkbox

Hey fellow Android Developers, Im having a issue currently with the below code. I am unable to figure out a way i can easily reference which Checkbox is clicked, Currently the code below is simply a Preference that when clicked, displays a AlertDialog with multiple Checkboxes.

The goal is do something specific when that Checkbox is checked, however i want to do something different possibly with each item.

### Code

```
Preference checkboxalert = (Preference) findPreference("checkboxalert");
           checkboxalert
            .setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        final CharSequence[] items = {" Easy "," Medium "," Hard "," Very Hard "};
        final ArrayList<Integer> selectedItems=new ArrayList<Integer>();

        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
               AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                 builder.setTitle("Select The Difficulty Level");
                 builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
                   new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected,
                                 boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) { 
                            //WHERE I WANT TO REFERENCE WHICH CHECKBOX IS CLICKED

                            selectedItems.add(indexSelected);
                            Log.i("Preference - Checkbox", "Something was clicked");

                             } else if (selectedItems.contains(indexSelected)) { 
                                 selectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
                             }
                         }
                     })
                     .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                         }
                     })
                     .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                         @Override
                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                         }
                     });
                        dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();

                return true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with using the `index`?

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected,boolean isChecked) 
{
    if (isChecked) { 
     selectedItems.add(indexSelected);

    //WHERE I WANT TO REFERENCE WHICH CHECKBOX IS CLICKED
    switch (indexSelected)
    {
         case 0:
            // do something if the first box is checked
            break;
         case 1:
            // do something if the second box is checked
            break;
         ...
    }
}
```

It seems like this should work unless I am missing what you want.

Comment: This works perfectly, For some reason i didn't think to do it like this. I guess my original approach was trying to reference the checkboxes by the title instead of the index. But this is way better!.

Comment: Yeah, referencing in a way like this such as `index` or `resource id`, depending on what you are working with, is usually better and safer. If you decide to change, say "Hard" to "Difficult", then you don't have to change how you reference it.